# Lightswitch and Database load - best practise

Tags: database, visual-studio-lightswitch

After reading through some articles on LightSwitch, I'm left wondering what prevents a LightSwitch user creating queries that over load the data-source, mainly SQL databases.

From my initial understanding, a LightSwitch user is not a developer or DB admin, and may little understanding of the impact a seemingly simple query can have on a multi-user database.

Does LightSwitch have built in governance, caching etc, is it safe to let the user have access to the last years sales data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is anything built into LightSwitch for this, however this should be able to be handled on the DB server.

If you're running SQL Server 2008 they've got resource governance built in.

[MSDN SQL 2008 Resource Governance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx)

[Specific example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933944.aspx)